# Android list view add value

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

in Android list view can we set some value to each row just like we do in web programming

```
<td id="123">Display</td>
```

How can this be done in android.I use the following code for list view display

```
ArrayList<String> filelist = new ArrayList<String>();
final ListView mainlist   = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
....
....
for (int l=0;l<lines.length;l++)
{
     filelist.addAll( Arrays.asList(lines[l].toString())) ; 
}
ArrayAdapter adp = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, filelist);
mainlist.setAdapter(adp);
mainlist.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

Comment: you mean to say,you want to attach unique value to each of your listitems?

Comment: may be unqiue or may be the same and onclick of the item get that value too

Comment: ok...then you have to implement custom adapter class and you can set tag to each item there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

**CustomAdapter.class:**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    Context mContext;
    String[] list;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public static HashMap<Integer, Integer> hashkeys=new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        list=objects;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mContext=context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         final ViewHolder holder;

         if(convertView==null)
         {
              convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_item, null);
                 holder = new ViewHolder();

                 holder.tv=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview);                
                 convertView.setTag(holder);
         }
         else
         {   
            holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
         }
         int value=0;
         switch(position){
             case 0:
                value=1;
                break;
             case 1:
                value=2; 
                break;
             case 3:
                value=3;
                break;                  
         }
         hashkeys.put(position,value);         

         return convertView;
    }
    static class ViewHolder
    {
            TextView tv;            
    }
}
```

Now in your activity,

```
CustomAdapter adp = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_item, filelist);
mainlist.setAdapter(adp);
mainlist.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

mainlist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                        long id) {

            String unique_value=CustomAdapter.hashkeys.get(position);//get value on click of item

        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void setList(int viewId, String[] title_list) {
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(viewId);
    ArrayAdapter<String> titlesAdaptor = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            title_list);

    listView.setAdapter(titlesAdaptor);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            listOnClicked(view, position, id);
        }
    });

}// end of setList

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
    //handle click events here
}
```